# Quotient of union of two spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $f : S^{n-1} \to X$ and $Y := X \cup_f D^n = \big(X \coprod D^n\big) / \sim$  , where $t \sim f(t)$ for $t \in S^{n-1}$.

**Problem.** Prove that $Y/X \cong S^n$.

**My idea.** The picture I have is a ball $D^n$ with $X$ around it and $X$ attached to the boundary $S^{n-1}$ at some points. But then identifying $X$ with a single point (making $Y/X$) would leave the interior of $D^n$ untouched and might identify points on the boundary, resulting in something that does not look like $S^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You more or less have the idea. Since every point of $X \subseteq Y$ is collapsed to a point, and in $Y$ every point of $S^{n-1} = \partial D^n$ is mapped to $X$, the quotient $Y/X$ is precisely $D^n / S^{n-1}$, which is $S^n$.

More precisely, you can prove that $Y/X = (X \sqcup D^n) / {\approx}$ where $t \approx x$ for all $t \in S^{n-1}$ and all $x \in X$. You can then define a map $Y/X \to D^n/S^{n-1}$ by first defining 'the obvious map' $X \sqcup D^n \to D^n/S^{n-1}$ and showing it respects $\approx$. The map on the quotient by $\approx$ is a homeomorphism, which is easy to prove (it's essentially just the identity map!).